# Is the MWI symmetric in time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, time-reversal-symmetry

Reading the blog of Sean Carroll (I recognize he isn't the only voice) has made me more sympathetic to the notion of many worlds, but reading Susskind (also not the only voice) has made me think that time-reversibility is important.

I understand that collapse theories aren't reversible, but I've been wondering about the [MWI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation). Does decoherence of worlds occur "backwards"?

I'm trying to imagine this, and I'm coming up with weird mental images wherein several different quantum states cohere into the same one, but this doesn't really make sense and there doesn't seem to be any reason for it to occur. Yet if it doesn't occur, (it seems to me) that MWI is not time-symmetric as (it seems to me) it should be.

Have a lot of other people thought about this before? What do they have to say?

EDIT: Is this, and other reversibility concerns in QM, related to our other familiar asymmetry -- entropy? Or is that crazy?

Comment: MWI is perfectly time-symmetric, just like every other formalism of quantum mechanics. The irreversibility is a second-law-type thing; it's very unlikely for two distinct 'worlds' to recohere for the same reason you won't see an egg uncook itself.

Comment: Both in thermodynamics/statistical mechanics and relativity. Think about the consequences of the speed of light for a local observer: the local observer can't catch a light wave (or, for that matter, any other massless field). This automatically creates a fundamentally irreversible loss of state information for any local definition of physics. MWI comes at this with "god's eye" by proposing a completely irrelevant (since unmeasurable) global wave function. It then analyzes this without any consequences for what would really happen if god measured this entity: a quantum zeno.

Comment: Thats a really interesting thought. Can you elaborate on the meaning of "quantum zeno"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Zeno_effect. It's basically the consequence of repetitive measurements. Every measurement of a system puts it into a new initial state. If the time evolution of the state is slow compared to the rate of the measurement, the system will stay near the initial state forced on it by the measurement. When the rate increases towards infinity (i.e. the measurement becomes continuous), then the state will essentially be frozen.

Comment: I think this has been pointed out by many authors: $H\psi_{Universe}=0$. There is no time development, at most one can think of local observers tracing out different (random?) projections of a very complex "pre-ordained" static object. If that appeals to you as an interpretation, it has the great advantage over MWI that it only needs one entity, rather than infinities of infinities potentiated to infinity of them.

Comment: Geez that's weird (zeno effect). Thanks for the insight and the reading.

Comment: The past is as uncertain as the future, by the way. We can't know the past quantum state from a measurement in the present any better than we can know the future quantum state. From the present perspective multiple possible past quantum states could have lead to the current quantum state and the current quantum state can lead to multiple possible futures. I think that's really all that the wave function tells us: the past is being forgotten by nature and the future is open.

Comment: The measurements in QM are self-evidently irreversible http://motls.blogspot.com/2016/05/measurements-are-fundamentally.html?m=1 as logical steps and whatever is claimed to replace them must be irreversible as well. What the MWI advocates say is that they "want" some "theory" or "interpretation" that is completely reversible but it's obvious that nothing of the sort may exist. No "MWI theory" exists mathematically - it's just a collection of propaganda and wishful thinking. Irreversibility is a nice window to see that all realist replacements for QM must be wrong.

Comment: re: your edit (is measurement in MWI related to entropy increase?). This is indeed an avenue I've seen pursued by some people. Essentially, the idea is that: if there's a way by which reversible classical mechanics (Hamilton's equations) becomes macroscopically irreversible, then the same sort of idea should apply in quantum mechanics (Schrodinger equation). Entropy increase in QM is indeed closely related to decoherence and measurements, and this is especially apparent in the density matrix viewpoint.

Comment: @LubošMotl Thanks for the link. Can you clarify a bit? I perceive a difference between "in principle" and "in practice" irreversibility; i.e. in classical mechanics, the time reverse of every allowable interaction is also allowable (right?), and yet the time-reverses occur with vanishingly small likelihood (often credited to the 2nd Law). I understand that QM is in practice irreversible (obviously), but are you making a stronger claim than that? By your final remark, should I understand you to mean that the wavefunction is a fiction?

Comment: @DevinPatterson - you've almost said all the right things. Exactly, classical physics may be made in principle reversible - if you assume that all the $x(t)$ trajectories are known. The probabilistic description in classical physics in terms of $\rho(x,p,t)$ is irreversible because of the moments when the observer learns some information and $\rho$ "collapses". This is irreversibility just in "practice", as you said, because one may always assume that there's a perfect observer who knows some $x(t)$, i.e. $\delta$-function-like $\rho$, which cannot collapse more than it is.

Comment: Now, the difference of quantum mechanics is that the density matrix *cannot* be equivalent to a delta-function-like $\rho$. The uncertainty principle guarantees that the most accurate physically possible probability distribution on the phase space is still "spread" over some region of area $2\pi\hbar$ or its power. It means that all the irreversible effects of the collapse of $\rho(x,p,t)$ in classical physics that could be eliminated in principle cannot be eliminated in QM, not even in principle. The uncertainty *principle* is what turns the "irreversibility in practice" to ir. in principle.

Comment: *Please* define specialized acronyms on first use *especially* when used in the subject line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the many-worlds interpretation is supposed to be time symmetric.

Consider this toy example with a particle than can be in either of the states $\left|1\right\rangle$ or $\left|2\right\rangle$. Additionally, we denote the no particle state as $\left|0\right\rangle$.

The particle gets emitted by our source $S$ that can be in its ground state $\left|S_0\right\rangle$, in a state $\left|S_1\right\rangle$ ready to emit a particle in state $\left|1\right\rangle$ or in a state $\left|S_2\right\rangle$ ready to emit a particle in state $\left|2\right\rangle$.

Eventually, the particle gets absorbed by a detector $D$ that can be in its ground state $\left|D_0\right\rangle$, in a state $\left|D_1\right\rangle$ after absorption of a particle in state $\left|1\right\rangle$ or in a state $\left|D_2\right\rangle$ after absorption of a particle in state $\left|2\right\rangle$.

Let the time evolution of the states of interest be given by the discrete steps
$$
\left|S_1\right\rangle\otimes\left|0\right\rangle\otimes\left|D_0\right\rangle
\longrightarrow \left|S_0\right\rangle\otimes\left|1\right\rangle\otimes\left|D_0\right\rangle
\longrightarrow \left|S_0\right\rangle\otimes\left|0\right\rangle\otimes\left|D_1\right\rangle
$$
and
$$
\left|S_2\right\rangle\otimes\left|0\right\rangle\otimes\left|D_0\right\rangle
\longrightarrow \left|S_0\right\rangle\otimes\left|2\right\rangle\otimes\left|D_0\right\rangle
\longrightarrow \left|S_0\right\rangle\otimes\left|0\right\rangle\otimes\left|D_2\right\rangle
$$
Note that this is not how unitary time evolution works in quantum mechanics, and I'll get back to that at the end.

So, what happens if we start out in a state $\left|S_1\right\rangle + \left|S_2\right\rangle$?<sup>1</sup>
$$
\left(\left|S_1\right\rangle+\left|S_2\right\rangle\right)\otimes\left|0\right\rangle\otimes\left|D_0\right\rangle
\\\longrightarrow \left|S_0\right\rangle\otimes\left(\left|1\right\rangle+\left|2\right\rangle\right)\otimes\left|D_0\right\rangle
\\\longrightarrow \left|S_0\right\rangle\otimes\left|0\right\rangle\otimes\left(\left|D_1\right\rangle+\left|D_2\right\rangle\right)
$$

This is symmetric in source and detector and time symmetry is manifest. However, in our subjective experience, we only ever see detectors in a state $\left|D_1\right\rangle$ *or* $\left|D_2\right\rangle$ - we have no concept of a detector in a superposition of states $\left|D_1\right\rangle+\left|D_2\right\rangle$, its pointer indicating two values simultaneously.

Some people argue (or at the very least, have done so historically) that the state must have collapsed through one of the (non-unitary) physical processes
$$
\left(\left|1\right\rangle+\left|2\right\rangle\right)\otimes\left|D_0\right\rangle \longrightarrow \left|0\right\rangle\otimes\left|D_1\right\rangle
$$
or
$$
\left(\left|1\right\rangle+\left|2\right\rangle\right)\otimes\left|D_0\right\rangle \longrightarrow \left|0\right\rangle\otimes\left|D_2\right\rangle
$$

Others claim that the 'collapse' is merely apparent, a Bayesian update of our information about the world, and the quest for ways to achieve objective collapse is indicative of a fundamental misunderstanding of the nature of reality as revealed by modern physics.

Proponents of the MWI argue that the most sensible resolution is to consider the observer (including their subjective state of mind) as intrinsically liked to $D$, ie we can consider the detector with its macroscopically distinct pointer states as a proxy for the relevant parts of the environment. The asymmetry arises because the observer was blind to the microscopic state of the source, but sensitive to the macroscopic state of the detector, and a time reversal would include a process of memory erasure.

It should be noted that the toy model I presented is cheating, which is why I had deleted my answer:

Emission and absorption are not just given by unitary time evolution like
$$
U(t_i, t_f) \left( \left|S_1\right\rangle\otimes\left|0\right\rangle \right) = \left|S_0\right\rangle\otimes\left|1\right\rangle
$$

Instead, we're dealing with stochastic processes (the source could in principle stay in its excited state indefinitely), and there's already a 'collapse' implied by the discrete time evolution of the toy model that was glossed over.

However, I suspect the line of reasoning I presented here would make sense in a [consistent histories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_histories) approach to the many-worlds interpretation.

For now, I'll leave the answer as-is - I'm not sure I can come up with a better one without a few sessions of late-night (or beer-fueled) philosophizing...

---

<sup>1</sup> we ignore issues of phase and normalization

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. So, in reverse, the detector emits the superposed state |1⟩+|2⟩ which decoheres into sources S1 and S2? Doesn't this imply that I came, with certainty, from either the S1 branch or the S2 branch (rather than a superposition thereof)? Doesn't this replace the branching quantum universe with a bunch of non-intersecting classical ones? I hope I haven't gotten too confused.

Answer (score 0):

The MWI interprets quantum physics roughly as follows:

1. Everything everywhere and at all times evolves via Schrodinger's equation.
2. What constitutes physical reality, and is described by quantum physics, is not so much a set of things as a set of correlations.

An example of item 2 here is given by entangled states. When a particle decay results in the death of a cat, for example, then the final situation is not one in which cat is alive or dead, but rather one in which there is a correlation between the state of the particle and the state of the cat, says MWI. This seems plausible at first, but in order to make it consistent one has to also solve the preferred basis problem and make sense of the concept of probability.

I feel that since one has to solve the preferred basis problem anyway, one may as well say there is just one branch as say there are vast numbers of branches and all but one of them are irrelevant to our present and future experience. The latter claim does not sound like good physics to me. This makes MWI, for me, not a strong contender for a correct account of physics. But it is not easy to argue convincingly for either view in our present state of knowledge.

The main thing in answer to your question is that in view of item (1) above, the MWI interpretation is time-reversible. (I can't resist adding that I personally don't think the physical universe is time-reversible, so to me this is a major weakness of MWI, but I don't have a sufficiently persuasive model to resolve this debate.)

If one takes some physical process and runs it backwards, then we get weird things such as broken eggs coming back together and leaping off the floor. But any view of physics should conclude that time running backwards is weird, simply because it genuinely would be weird as soon as processes of sufficient complexity are involved. So it is ok that the MWI suggests very odd things would happen if we applied a time-reversal to the dynamics of the universe. The MWI interpretation would account for the odd observations in the same way that classical physics would account for reducing entropy in a time-reversed dynamics: one would say there were many very special correlations in the conditions from which the time-reversed dynamics set out (the conditions which were final conditions really, but which we are turning into initial conditions in this thought-experiment).